# What exactly is the Nullify delete rule doing?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Does that mean that if I delete an managed object which has references (relationship) to some others, the relationships are removed to those others?

Example: objectA references objectB and objectC. objectA gets deleted, it's relationship to objectB and objectC is set to the Nullify rule. What happens in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk traditional bicycles and owners instead of generic A, B, C.

```
Bicycles (id, type, owner_id...) = (17, "Fast One", 31...)
Owners (id, name...) = (31, "Joe Biker"...)
```

if `owner_id` is a foreign key into `owners` set to `nullable`, and you delete `"Joe Biker"` from the `owners`, `"Fast One"`'s `owner_id` changes from `31` to `NULL`.